# Strange bug while combining images in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a hundred 10x10 px images, and I want to combine them into a big 100x100 image. I'm using the Image library to first create a blank image and then paste in the smaller images:

```
blank = Image.new('P',(100,100))
blank.paste(im,box)
```

The smaller images are in color, but the resulting image turns out in all grayscale. Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably something to do with using a palette type image (mode P). Is there a specific reason you are doing this? If not, try passing `'RGB'` as the first argument.

Comment: Perfect. I was saving it as a PNG, so I thought I should be using mode 'P'. Turns out that's not true. Thanks!